# Effect of adding a damped linear function to a nonlinear dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, perturbation-theory, stability-theory

I am trying to analyse the effect of adding a linear term to a nonlinear system. Specifically, for $\vec{x}=(x_1,...x_n)$, the original dynamical system is given by:

$\frac{d \vec{x}}{dt} = f(\vec{x}) \hspace{5cm} (1)$

where $f(\vec{x})$ is quadratic in the $x_i$. For this system, I know the system is neutrally stable at the fixed point. That is, it will oscillate in proportion to the initial magnitude of the disturbance.

Now I am adding a linear perturbation to this system, based on some linear operator $A$ that is full rank:

$\frac{d \vec{x}}{dt} = f(\vec{x}) + A\vec{x} \hspace{3.75cm} (2)$

I would like to try to understand what the necessary or sufficient conditions are for when this additional term damps the system,  such that the oscillations decrease over time, i.e., I'd like to show under what conditions this linear term leads to stability (either local or global). Note that in general, the solution to Eqns. (1) and (2) will be different, since the original solution $\vec{x}_0$ need not be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue zero.

Are there any good tools to show that the inclusion of the linear $Ax$ term makes the fixed point stable? I have considered looking at perturbation theory, but I don't really care about showing that the perturbations have no effect on the value of the equilibrium point --- I really just want to show that adding the perturbations damp the oscillations and cause it to converge over time. Alternately, I have considered looking at damped oscillators, but I can't find any general theoretical results that apply broadly to general equations.

Anyone one have any suggestions of how to attack this or specific approached to take?

Thanks!

Edit: just to clarify, I'm not asking about general practical approaches to showing stability. My question is more theoretical in nature. Are there known results or theorems that can deterring under what conditions this inclusion of a linear term can stabilize a nonlibear system?

Comment: It seem that @MrYouMath already gave you a complete answer, so please clarify your question in case you meant something else.

Comment: MrYouMath gave a general approach for showing local stability. My question is more broadly about the necessary or sufficient conditions for determining when the addition of a linear operator to a nonlinear term stabilizes the system. That is, my question is more about perturbation theory than general stability analysis. I've added a few points of clarification in the post.

Comment: Now that you have made the clarification, undoubtedly you should follow the answer that you already have. You see, the point is that once you have a nonzero linear term there is no other possibility: either at least there is a positive eigenvalue and you have instability, or not in which case you have asymptotic stability or should use center manifold theory. Note that your question is about the extremely particular question of what happens in the **autonomous case** (as the answer also, but it is for your question).

Comment: Certainly linearizing the system or exploring the Jacobain is a standard approach. But in my case this is not feasible, hence why I'm wondering about more general mathematical results from perturbation theory. For example, Fred Brauer had a whole bunch of general results about how the inclusion of linear terms affects the fixed points on non-linear systems, which does not rely on linearization, but rather on general properties of the linear and non linear operators. And so I'm wondering if there are similar general mathematical theorems to understanding stability.

Answer (score 0):

Linearize the system at the origin. If the resulting system with coefficient matrix $\hat{A}$ is asymptotically stable it is guaranteed by  Lyapunovs converse theorem that you can find a Lyapunov function $V=x^TPx$ for the nonlinear system by solving the Lyapunov Equation

$P\hat{A}+\hat{A}^TP=-I,$

in which $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately the linearized system is not in general asymptotically stable.

Comment: Does it have eigenvalues with positive real part? If yes, then the origin of the nonlinear system is unstable. If it has only negative real part eigenvalues but also with real part zero solutions then you might be able to use the center manifold theory.